# What does "MLB 2020 season simulation" mean?

Tags: mlb

MLB was supposed to launch the 2020 regular season on March 26 and was postponed due to COVID-19.

A [post](https://www.cbssports.com/mlb/news/mlb-2020-season-simulation-bryant-wainwright-suspended-for-scuffle-bellinger-gets-nearly-200m-extension/) says

> MLB 2020 season simulation: Bryant, Wainwright suspended for scuffle; Bellinger gets nearly $200M extension

What does that mean? Is "MLB 2020 season simulation" some kind of online video game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the MLB season cannot be played due to the novel coronavirus, the staff of writers responsible for the article (CBS Sports) decided to execute a simulation using [Out Of The Park 21](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1087280/Out_of_the_Park_Baseball_21/), a video game, as referenced twice in that very article.

> Here's how the regular season's third week played out in Out of the Park 21
>
> Because we could all use a distraction these days, we've decided to pass time by simulating the season on Out of the Park Baseball 21.

---

> Is "MLB 2020 season simulation" some kind of online video game?

No.

> What does [MLB 2020 season simulation: Bryant, Wainwright suspended for scuffle; Bellinger gets nearly $200M extension] mean?

This means a staff of writers simulated the third week of the regular season using a video game, and the results were a scuffle and contract extension.